# How do I apply .agg to the top n items in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to pull back a dataframe object computed from the top 4 items of a larger data set. To do this I've pulled the created a data frame `census_df` then written the following

```
return (census_df.set_index('STNAME','COUNTY')
            .nlargest(4,'CENSUS2010POP')
            .groupby(level=0)['CENSUS2010POP']
            .agg([{'Sum':np.sum}]))
```

which returns the four largest counties rather than all states with their population estimated by the four largest counties inside those states. 
I tried using

```
return (census_df.set_index('STNAME','COUNTY')
            .nlargest(4,'CENSUS2010POP')
            .groupby(level=0)['CENSUS2010POP']
            .agg([{'Sum':np.argsort()[-3:].sum()}]))
```

but `argsort` is missing a positional argument and I'm not sure what to put there -- what would `argsort` even reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
census_df.set_index('STNAME','COUNTY').\
      groupby(level=0)['CENSUS2010POP'].\
         agg(lambda x: x.head(4).sum())
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. How would I be able to sort that in the same call?

Comment: @Josh you can add `sort_values()`, PS if it help you , you can accept it : -)

Comment: @Josh Yeah, If still have any problem with the code above , let me know :-)